# How to auto update Date/Time field before save

Tags: field-update

When creating a reservation the end date should auto update with the value of the start date (plus a buffer) immediately, and thus before the record i saved.How should I try to tackle this problem?
I am still new to salesforce and thus this question might be trivial.
I have already tried to implement this functionality as a flow, but I could only get it to update upon a save.

[image: Image showing Date Picker of start and end]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Community!!. Please try `Fast Field updates` type flow to do the before updates and try populate the end date value logic using `Assignment` component. That's all. Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_record.htm&type=5

Comment: @Raj My understanding of the question is that OP wants this to happen before clicking the Save button. In that case, using fast field updates/a before-save flow wouldn't accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Updating upon saving is the only thing that can be done with Salesforce's standard UI. A flow (as you've used), a formula field (which is evaluated every time a query is run or a page is visited) or a trigger (using Salesforce's proprietary, java-like language called Apex) are the primary ways to accomplish that.

The thing that you're asking for would require you to basically write your own "edit" page/modal. You'd want to look at overriding the standard "edit" action for this object (setup -> object manager -> select your object -> actions, buttons, & links) and create a Lightning Web Component.

Honestly, it's almost certainly more trouble than it's worth.